# Wagtail - Reference form from child page

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm using the [Wagtail Form Builder](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8/reference/contrib/forms.html) so that site implementers can extend to create their own FormPage type with their own site-specific templates.

I want to **render all form pages on a parent page**; this includes all child page fields, such as the title, as well as the full child form.

Ideally, the submit button should also act on a per-form basis.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<ul>
    {% for child in page.get_children %}
    <li>

        <h5 class=>{{ child.specific.title }}</h5>

        <div>

            {{ child.specific.intro|richtext }}

            <div id="form-holder">

                <form action="{% child.pageurl page %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ child.specific.form.as_p }}
                    <input type="submit">
                </form>

            </div><!-- contact-form-holder-->

        </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

My form models are more or less as per the [Form Builder](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8/reference/contrib/forms.html) documentation with a few extra fields:

```
class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    db_table = 'form_field'

    page = ParentalKey('FormPage', related_name='form_fields')


class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    db_table = 'form_page'

    header = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FormSubmissionsPanel(),
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('header'),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Form fields"),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text', classname="full"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col6"),
            ]),
            FieldPanel('subject'),
        ], "Email"),
    ]
```

I've found that I can render the child page fields such as title and intro if I use the `.specific` method.

However, I can't seem to get any of the form to render; with or without the `.specific` tag.

Any help would be very welcome!

Comment: There is now an answer to a very similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673180/how-can-i-add-a-form-made-by-formbuilder-to-every-page-in-wagtail

Answer (score 0):

Off topic but maybe of any help:

{% for child in page.get_children %}

can be replaced by:

{% for child in page.get_children.specific %}