# How can I add a form made by formbuilder to every page in Wagtail?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, wagtail

Is there any way to add form (for example feedback form) to every page in CMS? I really like to use Wagtail FormBuilder so Editor guy can change fields.

My first idea is to create custom form page (inherited from AbstractEmailForm) as site root child and load it to base.html trough template tag. I can access page properties this way but I cant render the form.

Here is my template tag:

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_feedback_form(context):
  return context['request'].site.root_page.get_children().type(FeedbackFormPage).first()
```

And this is how I use it from base.html:

```
{% get_feedback_form as feedback_form %}
...
{{ feedback_form.specific.title }} <-- this works
{{ feedback_form.specific.form.as_p }} <-- this doesnt work
```

It would be nice somehow to create a form as snippet or add it to Site Settings, but I didnt find how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main issue is how you are generating the form in the template with `.form.as_p`.

You will need to generate the form with the .get_form function, but you are best to do it within your template as the current user and page needs to be past in as arguments like this.

```
        form = feedback_form_page.get_form(
        page=feedback_form_page, user=request.user)
```

You can see how the form is built for the AbstractForm model here:
https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailforms/models.py#L278

Full detailed example below, along with how you could work the form selection into the Site Settings module.

## Link to a Form in Site Settings

Assuming you are referring to the Site Settings contrib module:
http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13/reference/contrib/settings.html

The 'Edit Handlers' section of the documentation explains a great way to link to a page inside of your site settings.
http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13/reference/contrib/settings.html?highlight=site%20settings#edit-handlers

Example (in models.py):

```
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSetting, register_setting
# ...
@register_setting
class MyCustomSettings(BaseSetting):
    feedback_form_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    panels = [
        # note the page type declared within the pagechooserpanel
        PageChooserPanel('feedback_form_page', ['base.FormPage']),
    ]
```

Once you set this model up, you will need to do `makemigration` and `migrate` for the changes to work in admin. You will then see inside the settings menu a sub-menu titled 'My Custom Settings'

## Adding linked Form to every page

Add a block (so it can be overridden in templates) that has an include in your base template (eg. myapp/templates/base.html).

```
<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    {% block feedback_form %}{% include "includes/feedback_form.html" %}{% endblock feedback_form %}
    {% include "includes/footer.html" %}
</footer>
```

Create an include template (eg. myapp/templates/includes/feedback_form.html)

```
{% load feedback_form_tags wagtailcore_tags %}

{% get_feedback_form as feedback_form %}

<form action="{% pageurl feedback_form.page %}" method="POST" role="form">
  <h3>{{ feedback_form.page.title}}</h3>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ feedback_form.form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

## Build a Template Tag to get the form and page

Your template tag needs to build the form with the page's self.get_form() function. Eg. you your template tag (base/templatetags/feedback_form)

```
from django import template
from myapp.models import MyCustomSettings

register = template.Library()
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/


@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_feedback_form(context):
    request = context['request']
    my_custom_settings = MyCustomSettings.for_site(request.site)
    feedback_form_page = my_custom_settings.feedback_form_page.specific
    form = feedback_form_page.get_form(
        page=feedback_form_page, user=request.user)
    return {'page': feedback_form_page, 'form': form}
```

Comment: Thanks for great detail answer!

Answer (score 2):

This still works in wagtail 2.3 just need to replace

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
```

with

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True) to conform with django 2.2
```

Also `{% load feedback_form_tags wagtailcore_tags %}` assumes your file inside of templates tags is named feedback_form_tags.py. I also added an `__init__.py` in the template tags folder although I'm not sure that was actually necessary.