# Wagtail Feedback form in homepage

Tags: django, forms, wagtail

Tell me how to get the Wagtail form not in its separate template but on the homepage, since I do not need lending and another page. I can not find how to specify it in the get_context of the Home model

Comment: Do you want to get a Wagtail Form Builder Form inside your home page? This means that you have a FormPage model set up and you have something like a dedicated contact page or similar that already exists?  Or do you simply want to accept some kind of form on the home page that is written by the developer?

Comment: It might help to also put the code for your HomePage model and the relevant part of the template where you wish to put the form.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47214504/8070948

Comment: Yes that's right. As you said, I used all this and the form has a separate page. Those. on that page the form fields come (naturally), and the root (homepage) does not work, I think it's done via get_context, but I do not know how to get it right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to the question/answer about [putting a form on every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673180/how-can-i-add-a-form-made-by-formbuilder-to-every-page-in-wagtail/47214504#47214504).

Nonetheless, here is a way to implement this solution.

## Example

In your my_app/models.py -

```
class HomePage(Page):
    """A Page model that represents the home page at the root of all pages."""

    # must have way to know WHICH FormPage to use, this makes it user editable
    form_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='embedded_form_page',
        help_text='Select a Form that will be embedded on this page.')

    # ... all other fields

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Add a renderable form to the page's context if form_page is set."""
        # context = super(HomePage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs) # python 2.7 syntax
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if self.form_page:
            form_page = self.form_page.specific  # must get the specific page
            # form will be a renderable form as per the dedicated form pages
            form = form_page.get_form(page=form_page, user=request.user)
            context['form'] = form
        return context

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        PageChooserPanel('form_page', ['base.FormPage']), # Important: ensure only a FormPage model can be selected
        #... other fields
    ]
```

Then in your template my_app/templates/my_app/home_page.html

```
<div>
  {% if self.form_page %}
    <form action="{% pageurl self.form_page %}" method="POST" role="form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }} {# form is avaialable in the context #}
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

## Explanation

- First we provide a way to know which FormPage we want to render, we could assume by just grabbing the first one with `FormPage.objects.get()` but this is bad practice and could be unreliable. This is why we have added a ForeignKey to `wagtailcore.Page` - note we do not link to our FormPage model here.
- Then we restrict the linking inside the `PageChooserPanel`, in the example our `FormPage` model is located in the `base` app, hence `['base.FormPage]`.
- Then we override the `get_context` method, the only real reason we need to do this as it gets us the current `request` and `FormPage.getForm` needs the current request to be used.
- Finally, we update our template following the [form rendering example](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/forms/index.html#displaying-form-submission-information) in the docs pretty closely. With the difference being that our POST URL for the form is actually the form_page not the current page (homePage).
- Important Note: The form actually POSTS to the form page, not your home page, this means that we do not need to handle any kind of POST request to the home_page. It is a simple solution but it means that the landing page will be rendered ad the form page's URL.